# Does --init-file parameter support the creation of procedures through a .sql file?

Tags: mysql

So I have this SQL file whose contents are like below

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE FOO(....)
BEGIN
  Insert into BAR(...) Values(....);
  Insert into BARTOO(...) Values(...);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now this seems to work just fine when we I use the mysql client to execute this script. However If i pass it to initialize as a --init-file=./myscript.sql this fails with the follow error

> 2020-06-04T04:22:37.307204Z 5 [ERROR] [MY-000061] [Server] 1064  You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER
>   $$ CREATE PROCEDURE FOO(..... at line 1.

1. Initially this made sense that the keyword DELIMITER is not supported by the SQL syntax and that this is purely a client related command.Does that mean you cannot create a multi-line stored procedure using an --init-file? is there another way to create this procedure on initialization?
2. I also came across this bug report (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17843) that seems to indicate that DELMITER is supported in --init-file??

very confused, please help.

Answer (score 2):

I don't known about mysql but there's an open bug on mariadb : https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18394

The dev team seems to say that this is the same behavior as mysql. They are probably not going to fix this soon as this is marked as a feature request.

I don't know about the context in which you are using this init script, but in my case this is for a container initialization, which makes it hard to use the mysql client. I ended up using a small shell script as my entry point, starting the mysqld in the background with a minimal init file, waiting a little bit, then passing the commands with the mysql client, then putting the mysqld back to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Single-line procedures do appear to work in init files:

`init.sql`

```sql
USE mysql;
CREATE OR REPLACE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE abc() READS SQL DATA BEGIN SELECT 1; SELECT 2; SELECT 3; END;
```